# Device not recognised as registured in inTune Company Portal

Tags: office365, intune

I use Microsoft Office and the device is registered with inTune Company Portal. The device is registered with inTune successfully. However, when I try to login on Microsoft is informs me that the device is not registered and takes me to reinstall inTune. I can access Office365 online. This started when I logged in on my partner's profile and then tried to log back into my profile.

Comment: FAQ: [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 0):

Check that you haven't registered to many devices (default is 15 I think).  Also check in AAD (not Intune) the device has completed the registration, should list a registration date.  You might have to remove device from AAD and Intune, then start again to complete correctly.